# Alternatives to youtube iframe api?

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, swfobject

I'm giving up on using the youtube iframes api.  I use it with asp.net pages, and I use the youtube method of creating iframes programmatically, and I find that in Internet Explorer, those iframes are unreliable.  In chrome, they work fine.  So I need to have an alternative for IE.  I find the following code for a non-iframe youtube api:

```
 var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "player" };
    swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/v/<%=session("uTubeCode") %>?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3',
                       "player", '<%=Session("PlayerWidth")%>', '<%=Session("PlayerHeight")%>', "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

My question is two fold.  First, the above swfobject has to be declared from somewhere and initialized somewhere.  How do I do that?  Secondly, in my iframe code, I have attributes such as:

```
 { 'controls': 1, 'fs': 1, 'autoplay': 1, 'autohide': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0}
```

How do I put the equivalent of those into my swfobject?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1, if you just reference the SWFObject javascript library before calling the embedSWF method, the code should function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = ... etc.
```

To answer question 2, most of those attributes would be passed as parameters to the URL that embedSWF receives as an argument; to use your code as an example:

```
swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/v/<%=session("uTubeCode") %>?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&fs=1&autplay=1&modestbranding=1',
                       "player", '<%=Session("PlayerWidth")%>', '<%=Session("PlayerHeight")%>', "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

Here's the full list:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters